# Integration Rational Functions

Tags: integration

Hi guys I am quite stuck on this question, would really appreciate some help.
The finite region bounded by the curve with equation $y = \frac{2}{(x-1)(x-3)}$ and the lines $x = 4$ and $y = 1/4$ is denoted by $R$.
Show that the area $R$ is $\ln (3/2) - 1/4$

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Let 
$$
\frac{2}{(x-1)(x-3)} = \frac{A}{x-1} + \frac{B}{x-3}
$$
and find the values of $A$ and $B$ for which this is true.

Then,
$$
\int \frac{2dx}{(x-1)(x-3)} = A \int \frac{dx}{x-1} + B \int \frac{dx}{x-3}
$$
and the RHS becomes a pair of natural logs...

Comment: Ok so I have $a = -1  and  $b = 1

Comment: @m.bazza express area as an integral and use this technique to integrate -- you should be easily able to finish integration of the 2 elementary integrals on the RHS